# sp_executesql not working from databricks - pyodc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, azure-databricks, sp-executesql

Below is my sample databricks code where ACTUAL_TABLE and TEST_TABLE are SQL tables.

I am trying to insert into ACTUAL_TABLE from TEST_TABLE in databricks using pyodc connection.

`mssql_db.sql` is my connection and the connection is working as expected. Code executes without any error but not inserting any data into the table. Looks like `sp_executesql` not working from databricks.

```
V_SQL='INSERT INTO dbo.ACTUAL_TABLE(NAME,GENDER) SELECT ZNAME,GENDER from dbo.TEST_TABLE'
mssql_db.sql(f"""begin declare @V_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 
begin
set @V_SQL=N'{V_SQL}'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @V_SQL;
end
end""")
```

Is there any other way to fulfil this requirement. I wanted to insert it from databricks only.

I also tried creating the proc in SQL and calling that proc from databricks even that didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any data in TEST_TABLE?

Comment: Are you sure the code executes without error? It seems to be missing a `FROM`.

Comment: Sorry its a typo error, yes I do added from in the code and my source table has data

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below approach, I reproduce the same thing in my environment as per your requirement.

This is my demo table `ACTUAL_TABLE1`.

[image]

**Now, you can check Azure Databricks connected to the SQL server**

> **Code:**

```
import pyodbc
server = 'dem123.database.windows.net'
database = 'pool123'
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
    
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE='+ database +';UID=' + username + ';PWD='+ password)

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.ACTUAL_TABLE1 (NAME, GENDER) SELECT ZNAME, GENDER FROM dbo.TEST_TABLE'

cursor.execute(sql)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

[image]

**Successfully executed and inserted the data into ACTUAL_TABLE1 using above code:**

> **Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SaiVamsi as I said there is no issue with my connection and other tables are working fine. There was some audit enabled for this actual_table thats why its not getting inserted. I tried disabling the audit and I can see the data now in my ACTUAL_TABLE1